# Set a declared variable using a selection expression containing joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, variables

Early in my code, I have declared a variable (among other variables):

```
DECLARE @ZIPFk int;
```

Then, shortly thereafter, I try to SET the above variable's value using a selection expression that contains two joins:

```
SET @ZIPFk=(SELECT Zip.id 
FROM Zip
INNER JOIN Zip5 ON Zip5.id=Zip.Zip5Fk
JOIN PlaceName ON Zip5.PlaceNameFk=PlaceName.id
WHERE PlaceName.PlaceName=@USPSComm AND Zip5.ZipCode5=@ZIPCode)
```

It's not working and I can't figure out why. My resulting table just has a NULL value in the field where I expect/want the @ZIPFk value to be populated. When run on its own, apart from the declared variables, the SELECTION expression does result in a table with a single row/single column/single value.

Here is a look at the end of the query where the actual UPDATE occurs, using the declared variable:

```
UPDATE CompleteSubaddressZip 
SET ZipFk=@ZIPFk
FROM CompleteSubaddressZip as a
JOIN CompleteSubaddress AS b ON b.id=a.CompleteSubaddressFk  
WHERE (b.AddressUUID=@SelectedUUID)
```

And...here is a look at the entire thing:

```
USE MyDatabase;
DECLARE @USPSComm varchar = 'Springville' --<--Enter USPS ZIP community name here 
DECLARE @ZIPCode varchar = '99221' --<--Enter USPS ZIP Code here
DECLARE @RowsToProcess int;
DECLARE @ZIPFk int;
DECLARE @CurrentRow int;
DECLARE @SelectedUUID uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @UUIDTable table (RowID int not null primary key identity (1,1), UUID uniqueidentifier);

SET @ZIPFk=(SELECT a.id 
    FROM dbo.Zip AS a
    INNER JOIN Zip5 as b ON b.id=a.Zip5Fk
    JOIN PlaceName as c ON b.PlaceNameFk=c.id
    WHERE c.PlaceName=@USPSComm AND b.ZipCode5=@ZIPCode)            

INSERT INTO @UUIDTable (UUID) VALUES 
    ( 'f4x6faf4-bxx2-4166-bcd6-88c9af8ab546'), ('3e20xx5e-5edc-4735-8962-5ab3c50d053e'),
    ('696xxB2D-50DE-4361-807D-48xxD2AC5CxB')
    , ('c5879x41-e144-4ecc-8056-5493exxx1a5'), ('af7993cf-2xec-4c5f-b02e-92cb6dxxxf2b')

SET @RowsToProcess =@@ROWCOUNT 

SET @CurrentRow=0 
WHILE @CurrentRow<@RowsToProcess 
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentRow =@CurrentRow+1
    SELECT
        @SelectedUUID=UUID
        FROM @UUIDTable
        WHERE RowID=@CurrentRow

UPDATE CompleteSubaddressZip 
  SET ZipFk=@ZIPFk
    FROM CompleteSubaddressZip as a
    JOIN CompleteSubaddress AS b ON b.id=a.CompleteSubaddressFk  
    WHERE (b.AddressUUID=@SelectedUUID)
END
```

Comment: what do you mean by *not working*?

Comment: It's supposed to UPDATE a field in one of my tables with the @ZIPFk value, but instead, it updates it to NULL. I'll update my original post (above) with that part of my query as well...

Comment: why using a loop? you can set all the records at once, plus you can probably do a join from your zip to zip5 to placemname to completesubaddresszip to completesubaddress to your UUIDTable and do it all in one statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize to any who might read this thread: my fumbling around and the fact that I'm not really sure what I've changed to correct my problem, renders this thread nearly useless.

However, for posterity, here is my final(?) query which actually works as intended. (I owe many thanks to the comments from user "Matt" who helped me clean things up and at least got me on the right track, and tell me when I was being daft). I took out the 'looping' and removed unnecessary variables and generally simplified everything:

```
USE MyDatabase;
DECLARE @USPSComm varchar (20)='Springfield'; --  <--Enter USPS ZIP community name here 
DECLARE @ZIPCode varchar (5)='97477'; --  <--Enter USPS ZIP Code here
DECLARE @ZIPFk int;

SET @ZIPFk=(SELECT x.id
FROM Zip AS x
INNER JOIN Zip5 as y ON y.id=x.Zip5Fk
JOIN PlaceName as z ON y.PlaceNameFk=z.id
WHERE z.PlaceName=@USPSComm AND y.ZipCode5=@ZIPCode);

UPDATE a
SET ZipFk=@ZIPFk
FROM CompleteSubaddressZip as a
JOIN CompleteSubaddress AS b ON b.id=a.CompleteSubaddressFk
JOIN Zip as c ON a.ZipFk=c.id
JOIN Zip5 as d ON c.Zip5Fk=d.id
JOIN PlaceName as e ON d.PlaceNameFk=e.id  
WHERE b.AddressUUID IN ('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-UUID-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
, 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-UUID-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
, 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-UUID-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
, 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-UUID-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
, 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-UUID-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ZIPCode varchar = '99221' --<--Enter USPS ZIP Code here
DECLARE @RowsToProcess int;
DECLARE @ZIPFk int;
DECLARE @CurrentRow int;
DECLARE @SelectedUUID uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @UUIDTable table (RowID int not null primary key identity (1,1), UUID uniqueidentifier);

SELECT TOP 1 @ZIPFk = Zip.id 
FROM Zip
INNER JOIN Zip5 ON Zip5.id=Zip.Zip5Fk
JOIN PlaceName ON Zip5.PlaceNameFk=PlaceName.id
WHERE PlaceName.PlaceName=@USPSComm AND Zip5.ZipCode5=@ZIPCode

INSERT INTO @UUIDTable (UUID) VALUES 
    ( 'f4x6faf4-bxx2-4166-bcd6-88c9af8ab546'), ('3e20xx5e-5edc-4735-8962-5ab3c50d053e'),
    ('696xxB2D-50DE-4361-807D-48xxD2AC5CxB')
    , ('c5879x41-e144-4ecc-8056-5493exxx1a5'), ('af7993cf-2xec-4c5f-b02e-92cb6dxxxf2b')

UPDATE CompleteSubaddressZip 
  SET ZipFk=@ZIPFk
    FROM
       CompleteSubaddressZip as a
       INNER JOIN CompleteSubaddress AS b
       ON b.id=a.CompleteSubaddressFk  
       INNER JOIN @UUIDTable u
       ON b.AddressUUID=u.UUID
```

Comment: I don't think it's a case of multiple values...The SELECTION query only selects one single value, when I run it on its own (with a little modification to make it work without the declared variables): one row, in a table with one column.

Comment: I did try running the entire query with the variable set more explicitly SET @ZIPFk=121, and that worked as expected.

Comment: Then that means your query to populate your variable is not returning any results and you need to fix your query.  I strongly suggest loosing the loop unless you are going to use it to batch update a few thousand+ (hundreds of thousands...+, millions...) records at a time

Comment: After much persistence I discovered that the UPDATE statement in my query needed LEFT JOINS for the relationships to the zip tables, instead of 'regular' JOINS.

Comment: hmmmm that definitely doesn't seem likely....Actually it seems impossible if you are truly wanting to find the record with a specific UUID.  If you put left joins in how will you guarantee that the record you update is the right AddressUUID?  IF you put it in the where clause then your left join just becomes an inner join.....  did you perhaps change your test case to a different values?  If so, it is likely that your first test case doesn't have a corresponding value  in your first query to populate your variable and your solution appeared to work because of the difference.

Comment: Yes - upon further review, you're right....shouldn't have anything to do with the joins. I must have changed something else that I wasn't aware of. But I do know that my final "UPDATE" statement, when I tried to amend it into a "SELECT" query (as a test) didn't result in a selection of any records.